# C# getting each object from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I understand that my sample is not a good way of getting each object from a list.  Here's my sample:

```
var getWeeks = GetWeeks();
        var startOfWeek6 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek6;
        var endOfWeek6 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek6;
        var startOfWeek5 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek5;
        var endOfWeek5 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek5;
        var startOfWeek4 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek4;
        var endOfWeek4 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek4;
        var startOfWeek3 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek3;
        var endOfWeek3 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek3;
        var startOfWeek2 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek2;
        var endOfWeek2 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek2;
        var startOfWeek1 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek1;
        var endOfWeek1 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek1;
```

Do you have the ideal or simplier method?  Here's my sample how they're being used:

```
var transactionWk6 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek6 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek6.AddDays(1)) 
            .GroupBy(a => 1)
            .Select(d =>
                d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the use case for this? Can you show some more specific code on how the start/end weeks are used?

Comment: Well you can get each object from a list using a `foreach` loop, but from what I see in your example you're only accessing one element in the list. Did you mean you're looking for a cleaner way to access your *properties*?

Comment: I'm using it for my dataSet.Tables query.  Here's an example:
    var transactionWk6 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek6 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek6.AddDays(1)) 
                .GroupBy(a => 1)
                .Select(d =>
                    d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("TranCount"))
                ).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Add ^^^ that to your question.

Comment: That's correct.  I'm not sure if the loop will work.

Comment: When I tried this loop below, it says it was never used:

    foreach (var c in getWeeks)
            {
                DateTime startOfWeek6 = c.startOfWeek6;
               
            }

Comment: Define startOfWeek6 outside the foreach. Anyway, if what you want is to access all the properties of each list object, you can't do easily without using reflection.

Comment: Do you have a simple example?  Here's my my loop:

    foreach (var c in getWeeks)
            {
                WeekDates dtwk = new WeekDates
                {
                    startOfWeek6 = c.startOfWeek6
                };

            }

Comment: can you tell me how @Pikoh?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer and it works.

```
   public WeekDates GetWeeks()
   {
      result.totaltransaction = new WeekDates
        {
        startOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay),
            endOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6),

            startOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 7),
            endOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 7),

            startOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 14),
            endOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 14),

            startOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 21),
            endOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 21),

            startOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 28),
            endOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 28),

            startOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 35),
            endOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int) now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 35)

return result;
```

}

And here how I called them:

```
var getWeeksData = GetWeeks();
        var getWeeks = getWeeksData.totaltransaction;           

        var startOfWeek6 = getWeeks.startOfWeek6;
        var endOfWeek6 = getWeeks.endOfWeek6;
        var startOfWeek5 = getWeeks.startOfWeek5;
        var endOfWeek5 = getWeeks.endOfWeek5;
        var startOfWeek4 = getWeeks.startOfWeek4;
        var endOfWeek4 = getWeeks.endOfWeek4;
        var startOfWeek3 = getWeeks.startOfWeek3;
        var endOfWeek3 = getWeeks.endOfWeek3;
        var startOfWeek2 = getWeeks.startOfWeek2;
        var endOfWeek2 = getWeeks.endOfWeek2;
        var startOfWeek1 = getWeeks.startOfWeek1;
        var endOfWeek1 = getWeeks.endOfWeek1;
```